# Automatically changing field entry in related table when entering it in feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes, relates

I am working to try and develop a code or process that I can run that will allow me to automatically change an XY field in a related table when I change an associated XY field. Let me explain our situation a little first. We have a system where we are trying to maintain utility data in an SDE, and while doing this data is being entered by technicians in the field and brought back in. When data is entered in the field, there is a FACILITY_ID associated with each item, such as hydrants, values etc. This data is pushed to each cooresponding our feature class. However, when multiple actions are taken on the same feature, we are storing each of those changes in a different table while only reflecting the last action in the feature class. These two have a relationship class. So, there is only one entry for each FACILITY_ID in a feature class, but there may be multiple entries in the 'related' table for each FACILITY_ID.

Our problem is what to do if we move a hydrant/value in ArcMap and have to change the XY coordinate. We don't mind recalculating the X and Y values in the feature class table, but we would like a process that could recognize that change in the feature class XY and automatically change all of the X and Y values for the associated related table FACILITY_ID without having to go in and edit them by hand. Is there a simple way to do this? We've been looking at ArcObjects or ArcPy, but does a command like this already exist in ArcMap?

I should clarify, the 'related table' is more just a table that has a simple relationship class connected to the feature class. The second table in a non-spatial one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with SQL and actually copy the x,ys on an update, or drop the x,ys from the related table and use the matching ID in a view to get the values. That would keep the x,ys in one geo feature. Also you can look at cascading values in relationship classes in ArcGIS help.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking into the SQL solutions, and that might be the way to go. But, is there any way to do this within ArcMap without having to go directly to SQL (I'm also using version 10, so that might make a difference as well). Thanks for the response!